# ASP multiple repeater use same itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

In an .aspx page (.NET 2.0), I use several asp:repeater like this one :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="id_repeater" runat="server">
<headertemplate>
</headertemplate>
<itemtemplate>  
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1.1</td>
        <td>cell 1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 2.1</td>
        <td>cell 2.2</td>
    </tr>
</itemtemplate>
```

Every repeater has the same itemtemplate.

It works fine, but if I have to modify on itemtemplate, I need to update others...

An I'm a lazy developer ;) So I would like to know if it's possible to declare one time the itemtemplate and make all repeaters using it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the Repeater to a UserControl and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Create a user control somewhere and then use that as your item template.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="id_repeater" runat="server">
    <headertemplate>
    </headertemplate>
    <itemtemplate>  
        <my:control runat="server" id="myUserControl" />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own user control (ascx file) that will contain that repeater, then use it always when you need the same control.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than focusing on maintaining a separate item template, consider placing this in a [custom user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx). Any time you find yourself repeating similar blocks of code, you're probably missing an opportunity to move it into a class or a control.